# Como criar estrutura condicional em SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Necessito criar condições para o atributo `nome` e `idade`, os quais são:

- **Para o nome:** Rejeitar `nomes` que contenham a palavra `%mentiroso%`.
- **Para a Idade:** Rejeitar `idades` `< 1 || > 130`.

**Segue a criação de minha tabela:**

```
create table exemplo(id int PRIMARY KEY,
              nome char(30) not null....,
              idade ....,
              sexo enum('m', 'M', 'f', 'F'));
```

Comment: Você não conseguirá fazer isso apenas com mysql. Gostaria de te sugerir a fazer o [tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender como a comunidade funciona; depois leia o guia de [Como perguntar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) para verificar como pode melhorar sua pergunta, vale também dar uma lida em [Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Após isso poste seu código completo para que a comunidade possa te ajudar

Answer (score 0):

Na definição de sua tabela utilize a cláusula CHECK.

Para verificar a idade:

```
int idade CHECK (idade > 1 AND idade <=130),
```

Para o nome:

```
nome char(30) CHECK (nome NOT LIKE '%mentiroso%'),
```

Comment: não deu certo :(

Comment: O que deu errado ?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-check-constraints.html